# Transform value to negative if column has an string

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to transform an amount in python from positive to negative, I have the following table below:

| Receipt / Payment | Amount |
| --- | --- |
| Payment | 1233.0 |
| Receipt | 4561.3 |

What I'm trying to do is to check if the column receipt/payment is == to Payment then transform the amount to a negative value like so:

| Receipt / Payment | Amount | Amount 2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Payment | 1233.0 | -1233.02 |
| Receipt | 4561.3 | 4561.3 |

I have try doing this but the results aren't showing correctly:

```
df['Amount 2'] = df['Receipt / Payment'].where(df['Receipt / Payment'].str.contains('Payment'), -df['Amount'])
```

Any guidance on what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
df["Amount 2"] = df["Amount"] * np.where(
    df["Receipt / Payment"].str.contains("Payment"), -1, 1
)
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
  Receipt / Payment  Amount  Amount 2
0           Payment  1233.0   -1233.0
1           Receipt  4561.3    4561.3
```

Answer (score 1):

You were very well on the right track with df.where.

```
df['Amount 2'] = df.Amount.where(df['Receipt / Payment'].ne('Payment'), -df.Amount)
```

**Input**

```
    Receipt / Payment   Amount
0   Payment             1233.0
1   Receipt             4561.3
```

**Output**

```
    Receipt / Payment   Amount  Amount 2
0   Payment             1233.0  -1233.0
1   Receipt             4561.3  4561.3
```